# How do I access a property from the .vb file associated with the .aspx file?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

So In my somepage.aspx.vb I have this

```
Public Class somepage
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Protected Property StringToPass As String

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        StringToPass = "hello"
    End Sub
End Class
```

and then in the .aspx I try to do this

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="somepage.aspx.vb" Inherits="mywebpage.somepage" %>

...

<%=StringToPass%>

...
```

but this doesn't work as expected, the .aspx file has no idea of its existence. How do I get that string from A to B?

EDIT: actually it does work, when I load the page, the string is passed. Its just that the debugger thinks StringToPass is an undeclared variable, whats up with that?

Comment: "Protected" - may be too little of the scope

Comment: You probably just need to build the project before the aspx editor will see the property in the code behind.